# Random sign projection hash collision probability

Tags: probability

I am doing Locality Sensitive Hashing([LSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing)) where I hash based on random sign projections. That is each entry is hashed by drawing K planes in $R^d$ space and I hash them to a bit string. For each plane  I do $a^tx_i$ and assign a value of 1 if positive and 0 else. From [here](http://www.stat.rutgers.edu/home/pingli/papers/AsymmetricHashingNIPS2014UAI2015WWW2015.pdf) (section 2.2) I get that the probability of two vectors being hashed to the same bit is:

$$1-\cos^{-1}\left({\frac{x^Ty}{||x|| ~||y||}}\right)$$

Lets call this ps for simplicity. From here we can then calculate the probability of two vectors being hashed to the same bin when using $K$ planes and from that we can calculate the probability of getting at least one collision on $H$ repetitions of the hashing. Let $event$ be at least one collision in $H$ hashes using $K$ planes.

$$P(event) = 1-(1-ps^K)^H \tag{1}$$

Assuming x and y are scaled to have mean 0 and sd = 1 then $\frac{x^Ty}{||x|| ~||y||} = \operatorname{cor}(x,y)=\rho$.

So now given some known $K$ and $H$, we can calculate that two arbitrary vectors with correlation = $\rho$ have the probability (1) of colliding. For example, with K=6 and H=8, two vectors with correlation 0.8 have P(event) = 0.903.

What I am struggling to calculate is instead of calculating the probability based off of $\rho = x$ I want to calculate the collision probability given $\rho \geq x$. That is the probability of a collision given x and y have a greater than or equal correlation than x.